# rnd minimum width of node in decoration does not have same size in repeated code

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, decorations

I'd like to decorate path with double line of stars and expect the upper line of stars duplicate the lower ones. But why the stars in the `state{initial}` part are still random size.

I try to set mininum width, but it gives all same stars.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes.geometric,decorations.shapes,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{stars}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width=15pt ] {
        \pgfmathparse{round(rnd*100)}
        \pgfsetfillcolor{yellow!\pgfmathresult!orange}
        \pgfsetstrokecolor{yellow!\pgfmathresult!red}
        % set node mininum width
        %\pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width} }
        %\pgfset{minimum width=\pgfmathresult pt }

        \pgfnode{star}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}} % line lower stars
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{12pt}}  
        \pgfnode{star}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}} % line upper stars
    }
    \state{final} {
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    }
}
\draw[decorate, decoration={stars}, star point ratio=2,  star points=5, inner sep=0, minimum width=rnd*10pt+2pt] (0,0) -- +(5,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: stars]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myresult}{round(rnd*100)}` instead of using `\pgfmathresult` multiple times?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yeah, it works. `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myresult}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}` `\pgfset{minimum width=\myresult }` . Thanks.

Comment: It's strange the two `\pgfnode`  has different minimum width without explicitly setting the `/pgf/minimum width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access the result of a PGF calculation multiple times, it is better to store it in a macro using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. This is also the right way to store `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}` in a macro.

These two lines are needed to make the upper and the lower stars have the same size:

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myresultB}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}
\pgfset{minimum width=\myresultB}
```

Since you want to set `minumum width` to some random value, you need to prevent Ti*k*Z to calculate this value more than once. This is done with the two lines of code above where `minimum width` is internally set to the calculated random value, which will keep this value fixed when it is applied to the two stars.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, decorations.shapes}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{stars}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width=15pt] {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myresultA}{round(rnd*100)}
        \pgfsetfillcolor{yellow!\myresultA!orange}
        \pgfsetstrokecolor{yellow!\myresultA!red}
        % set node mininum width
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myresultB}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}
        \pgfset{minimum width=\myresultB}
        \pgfnode{star}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}} % line lower stars
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{12pt}}  
        \pgfnode{star}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}} % line upper stars
    }
    \state{final} {
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[decorate, decoration={stars}, star point ratio=2,  star points=5, inner sep=0, minimum width={rnd*10pt+2pt}] (0,0) -- +(5.5,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I debug the `\pgf\minimum width` after the two `\pgfnode`, they are different.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Is this not what you want to get?

Comment: there are two `\pgfnode`, every time the `\pgf\minimum width` of `\pgfnode` of lower star and upper star are different. That's not what I want, the solution is to explictly set `\pgf\minimum width`.

Comment: Then, don't use `minimum width={rnd*10pt+2pt}` but instead `minimum width=10pt` (or another fixed value).

Comment: I need to change `minimum width` for different decoration path。the longer the bigger star

Comment: So, where is the problem then? Just use `\draw[decorate, decoration={stars}, ..., minimum width=10pt]` for the first decoration and `\draw[decorate, decoration={stars}, ..., minimum width=15pt]` for the second. Sorry, I still don't get what you want to achieve ...

Comment: I try to control the star size by node option in `\draw[decorate, decoration={stars}, ..., minimum width=rnd*10]`, but not in the `\pgfdeclaredecoration`. And in the upper lines of stars, I expect every star with random size, but keep the upper and lower stars with same size. my apology for my poor english to express the idea

Comment: Sorry, you cannot chat due to low reputation. So, you want to set the minimum width randomly, but *all* the stars inside the macro should have the same size? Because, as it is now, every pair of stars (upper and lower) do have the same size.

Comment: yes, but in the `\pgfdeclaredecoration`, the `minimum width`s for two `\pgfnode` is different that is the problem.

Comment: It is like this: You set `minimum width` to `rnd*10pt` which will upon compilation result in, say, 12.4pt for a given decorated `\draw`. Then, in `\pgfdeclaredecoration` we now have `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myresultB}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}} \pgfset{minimum width=\myresultB}` which sets the minimum width to exactly `12.4pt` fix. Then both stars are drawn with the *same* minimum width.

Comment: when explictly setting the `minimum width` with `\pgfset{minimum width=\myresultB}`,then both paired stars(upper and lower) get  the same `minimum width`. that fix the problem.